# -moz-border-radius causes inline styles to be generated in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, mozilla, css

I am adding rounded corners to my website by including the style attributes for the major browsers -

```
.optional{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

When I load this up in IE8 though, the browser generates a bunch of inline styles, all of them overriding my previously defined styles. I do not want to add !important to all of these styles to keep them from being overridden.

Now, when I delete `-moz-border-radius: 10px;` everything works fine. I do not want to have to test that I'm not using IE and load a separate CSS file.

I have not been able to find anything online regarding this. Help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a compatibility script to add this CSS3 features to ie8? ie8 doesn't supports border-radius by default. If you are using such a script it could be creating elements with inline styles.

Comment: IE8 does not support any kind of border-radius and your script will be ignored, what ever the problem is you're having, it can't be caused by the border-radius properties you've defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 does not support border-radius property.[CSS compatibility-IE8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) You have to use behavior property. You can find the required .htc file and documentation here: [cross browser curved corner](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/)

Comment: You guys were right, turns out I had forgotten to remove the jquery curvy corners js file, which was the source of the problem in that I guess it generated a bunch of stuff if the -moz-border-radius tag was there. Appreciate the help